# What does it mean to "Use rendered output to group rows?"

Tags: views

Is the alternative to use raw output?
To what grouping is it referring?
Does this affect the sort order of rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have a node with a taxonomy term, then a normal list would look like this

- Title: A, Term 1
- Title: B, Term 2
- Title: C, Term 1
- Title: D, Term 3
- Title: E, Term 2
- Title: F, Term 1
- Title: G, Term 3

If you group them on the term, you would instead get something like this

- Term 1

  - Title A
  - Title C
  - Title F
- Term 2

  - Title B
  - Title E
- Term 3

  - Title D
  - Title G

Rendered is not related to raw/safe values. It's just a way of explaining that it's the rendered (displayed) values that are used as grouping field.

Comment: That nicely explains what using a grouping field does, but in D7, I can't see any effect generated by the "Use rendered output to group rows" -- it really seems like it does nothing at all to me.  I tried rewriting the output, wrapping it in HTML tags, etc -- and with or without that setting selected, the behavior is the same.  What is that setting supposed to be used for?

Answer (score 4):

This question is pretty old, but I was looking for the same thing just recently. Since the question wasn't really answered in previous posts, here's what this setting does - 
let's say you have a list of nodes grouped by date. Normally you'd get something like this:

- 12 January 2015

  - Title one
  - Title two
- 10 January 2015

  - Title three
- 24 December 2014

  - Title four
- 14 December 2014

  - Title five

But if you override date field in your view settings or using template to display just month and a year and then check “Use rendered output to group rows”, you will get this:

- January 2015

  - Title one
  - Title two
  - Title three
- December 2014

  - Title four
  - Title five

Note that nodes are grouped by months and years and not full dates, thanks to your overridden settings.

If you didn't check “Use rendered output to group rows”, you'd get this instead - nodes would be still grouped by original full date values, only labels would change:

- January 2015

  - Title one
  - Title two
- January 2015

  - Title three
- December 2014

  - Title four
- December 2014

  - Title five

Hope it clears some things.