# How to group this view?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that pulls data from the Speaker content type, as well as from related sessions (Session content type contains an entity reference to the Speaker, so to get that "reverse lookup" I'm using the "A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via field_speaker" relationship type to get the Content: Title from the session nodes.)

This all works, but I can't get the view to display the way I want when a speaker has more than one session. I've tried grouping by speaker name (Content: Title on the speaker node) and get this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Here's the basic view setup:

[image]

Can this be done just in the Views UI, or do I need to start fiddling with templates?

Comment: This is almost identical to the [question I just asked](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33746/hierarchical-grouping-in-views).

Comment: Sorry; I had started writing this post on Friday and just got around to submitting it - I didn't refresh the questions page so didn't see yours.

Comment: @EmmyS, is there an option within the Session field configuration for Group multiple values?  This is not grouping them in the Format section, but rather in the field configuration

Comment: @JohnathanElmore - no, there's not. I've only ever seen that on a taxonomy field. This is a reverse entity relationship, so a single session node can have two or three or more entity references to various speakers. What I need to do is display all of the sessions that have an entity reference to each speaker displayed in the view, which I can, but cannot get them grouped properly.

Comment: Is it possible the problem is Entity Relationships? http://drupal.org/project/er Looks like it's not stable yet

Comment: I'd recommend doing a relationship on the node reference instead of using entity relationship and see if you can group multiple values

Comment: We can't change the setup of the content types; there's already data in them. We need to work with what we have. Also, we're not using the module you referenced. We're using [this one](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference), which is most definitely stable and being used by more than 17,000 sites.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant but it's worth a try. I figured out the [answer to my similar question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33772/7256). Basically, have you tried checking the "remove tags from rendered output" checkbox?

Comment: Thanks; I tried that but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Not sure but try grouping with all the fields that are common between this 2 like the job title should also be in group so that it will be display only once.

Comment: @j2r - yup, that's what did it. Pain in the neck, because I have to completely rewrite my css to deal with 10-level nested divs generated by the grouping, but at least it displays the information we need. Thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept so you get the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but try grouping with all the fields that are common between this 2 like the job title should also be in group so that it will be display only once

Comment: Could you get more info, where I can use function "grouping all the fields"?